# Will it be a good idea to not include the language file in the main bundle at all to reduce the bundle size?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I am just thinking of ways to reduce the bundle size of my app. I just want to get feedback on a small thought I had. Will it be a good idea not to ship the language file at all in the main bundle of a application?

Because if your application too big with a lot of entries in the language file, it will start to take a small part of the bundle size, and if you have support for 2-5 languages in the app, then it can be even bigger part of your bundle size.

What if we removed the language files completely from the bundle and put it in a static get endpoint which will serve the static JSON of the language file and the get endpoint will be the 1st thing called when the app gets initialized?

Is it a somewhat of a feasible idea or am I completely crazy?

Comment: Why not use dynamic imports?

Comment: As with all performance questions, the answer is ["It depends. Measure before and after and see."](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0):

Heretic Monkey is right, you need to try it out and compare the performance.

Another consideration is that your interface might render in the default language before switching to the client language, if there's a long delay between the two resources this switch could be visually bothersome.

Personally I like to have each component have its own individual language files and have languages all be separate. So when you load a component of the page, the component quickly pulls a very small language file for itself in only the language it needs. Serving lots of small files like this works best when the server can serve HTTP/2 connections and lots of small files can be downloaded in parallel.
Caching is also important here, so if another of the same component loads it won't pull the same language file for itself again, it just grabs it from the cache.

As you suspect, separating everything out like this just might not be worthwhile depending on the size of the application and the number of languages you're supporting, so start by considering the size of your application and the size of the language portion. Does the language pack take up more than 10% of the file? Would that be worthwhile time savings?